# Google Cloud Functions Dashboard not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

the Google Cloud Functions dashboard has stopped working for me.. trying to navigate through tabs, but nothing happens.

It seems it happens only using chrome, works ok in safari...

[image: https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/us-central1/<your-function>...]

Any of you experiencing a similar issue?

Comment: If you're having a problem with the Cloud console, you should contact Google Cloud support directly. https://cloud.google.com/support

Comment: thank you @DougStevenson, done that already, wanted just to see if it was just us or it is a common issue

Comment: It sounds like you want to post to a discussion forum, not Stack Overflow.  SO is for programming problems, not polling people about transient issues with cloud platforms.  For the question you have now, there are only two answers: yes or no.

Comment: I just tested some of my projects and the Cloud console for Functions loads fine. You might want to 1) disable all plugins/extensions, 2) check for any errors in the JavaScript console. If those don't help, as Doug said: report the problem to Cloud as (while I can't say it's just you) it at least works for some people (me ).

Comment: Mine is working as well. @mikey are you still having issues? Have the suggestions mentioned by FrankvanPuffelen worked?

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your time. Turns out something went wrong on my deployment script and too many files were uploaded to each function. I think that was the reason the console wasn't responding.